# Was does the question mark after `Navigated to http://localhost:4200/?` in chrome log mean?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I've a really weird bug to hunt. It occurs on chromium (83) and chrome (84) but only on my Debian system. it does not occur neither on my colleagues Linux with chrome, nor on Firefox at my computer nor a any windows setup.

It that after submitting a matDialog in an angular-(9.0.6)-application, a routing (back) takes place which I can not explain. When I set `persist logs` on in chrome and chromium, I can see that after submitting the dialog, the browser somehow redirects. I searched all places in the code where `router.navigate` is called, but it's none if them. In Network-communication tab everything seems to be fine.

The bug is not reproducible on other machines. But on mine it happens with different program versions, with a local and online instances. I am quite desperate and have no clue what might be going on.

What I found is, that after the log-entry in the browser-console of the unwanted redirection there is a question mark:

[image]

The questionmark is blue, so it's not part of the URL, but part of the log-message. Does anybody knows what it could mean? Maybe the answer is a hint of what is going wrong here.

Btw. it's the same in chrome and chromium; both freshly installed respectively with all addons disabled.

Comment: Found similar thread on google support https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/29068832?hl=en this may help you investigate.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think this is the same. Since the `?` is blue, it is obviously *not* part of the URL but part of the browser's log message. But what does it indicate? Is Chrome usure if it navigated?

Comment: I've to correct myself. I I look really careful I can see the `?` in the URL bar for a glimpse than the redirection takes place. So actually it `is` part of the url it tries to go to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it was far more trivial than I thought. There was a hidden submit in the dialog, to allow closing it by pressing enter. It had not to d anything with the browser or OS, but how we closed the dialog, by pressing enter or by using the "ok" button.

```
<input matInput [formControlName]="bla" (keyup.enter)="matform.submit()">
```